PowerShell, automate Java JRE 11 (Adoptium, Eclipse Temurin) installation and configuration
I would like to automate the installation of Adoptium. So far, I have been able to download the latest version of the .msi
$baseURL = "https://api.adoptium.net/v3/assets/feature_releases/11/ga"   # Adoptium binaries and links

# Get versions and then [0] of the array that is returned to get the latest version
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseURL
$latestVersion = ($response.version_data.openjdk_version)[0]

# Locate the Windows MSI Installer
$downloadURL = ""
foreach ($asset in $response.binaries) {
    if ($asset.architecture -eq "x64" -and $asset.image_type -eq "jre" -and $asset.os -eq "windows") {
        $downloadURL = $asset.installer.link
        $downloadPath = "$env:TEMP\$($asset.installer.name)"   # Contains just the msi file name
        break
    }
}

# Download and run the installer
$global:progressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadURL -OutFile $downloadPath
& $downloadPath

After this, I want to automate the installation, but have not been able to get this to work. I have got to this so far, but it doesn't work. My goal is to auto-select the four available options in the JRE installer:

Add to PATH   (selected by default)
Associate .jar   (selected by default)
Set JAVA_HOME variable (not selected by default)
JavaSoft (Oracle) registry keys (not selected by default)

How can I use the Adoptium JRE 11 installer to auto-install it with all four of these options?
# Define the path to the MSI installer
$installerPath = "$env:TEMP\OpenJDK11U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.23_9.msi"

# Define the arguments for msiexec
$msiArgs = @(
    "/i", "$installerPath",    # Specify the path to the MSI installer
    "/qn",                      # Quiet mode (no UI)
    "/norestart",               # Do not restart after installation
    "INSTALLDIR=`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11`"",  # Specify the installation directory (change as needed)
    "ADDLOCAL=FeatureMain,FeatureEnvironment,FeatureJarFileRunWith,FeatureJNLPFileRunWith,FeatureJavaHome", # Specify features to install
    "SETUP_AUTO_UPDATE=0",      # Disable automatic updates
    "INSTALL_SILENT=Enable",    # Enable silent installation
    "ASSOCIATE_JNLP=Enable",    # Associate .jnlp files
    "ASSOCIATE_JAR=Enable",     # Associate .jar files
    "ASSOCIATE_JAD=Enable",     # Associate .jad files
    "INSTALLDIR_CONFESS=Enable" # Set installation directory
)

# Run msiexec with the defined arguments
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $msiArgs -Wait


if you want to install all features, change the value of the ADDLOCAL property :
ADDLOCAL=ALL

Thanks, I've not come across that before, will test this out.

informations about this property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/addlocal
